# XML Making PHP Unexpected String Error

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am getting this error

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   **/ho.../ssd/recording-goodbye.php** on line **1**

I have found that this line is causing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I think this is because short tags are enabled on this server, it's a shared hosting account and I don't have access to the php.ini file. Is there a way I can perhaps set the headers or escape this line?

This is the full content of recording-goodbye.php

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
<Response>
    <Say>Thanks for your recording.  Here is what I heard</Say>
    <Play><?php echo $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; ?></Play>
    <Say>Goodbye</Say>
</Response>
```

Comment: -1 Until you show me how you get into this error.

Comment: How I get into it? It's a printed in the debug console in Twilio

Comment: the xml tag can't produce that error. Post the first few lines of recording-goodbye.php

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code from recording-goodbye.php?

Comment: Very funny :-) What have you done in `/ho.../ssd/recording-goodbye.php`?

Comment: I have figured it out, sorry guys, I can't delete this, I don't know why it wasn't working without the echo, please see my answer

Comment: It wasn't working because your xml was being interpreted as PHP due to short_tags use.

Comment: The next things you want to consider why you do require/include to XML file?

Comment: It's for a twiml response, that is required for a twilio call, I'm using this example: http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/twilio-client-record

Comment: Proper XML parsing like DOMDocument, simplexml does not help?

Comment: Thanks for your help ajreal! I think I figured it out, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed it

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
```

Comment: Please put the existing code in your question so it can help others who stumble on this. Without it, there is little to no context. If it's true that you've labeled an xml file with a .php extension then you probably have other issues.

Comment: Ok I put the full code inside my question, an echo inside the xml file was why the php extension was necessary

Answer (score 2):

Try the technique described here: http://www.bin-co.com/php/articles/using_php_short_tags.php

It involves treating your xml file so that when it's interpreted by a php configuration using short tags, it will still come through as XML.